# How to have 5 flex elements in CSS, 3 on one row, and 2 on the next row, which are all the same fluid width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Say I have 5 "flex" elements with `flex-wrap` turned on and `flex-direction: row`. I would like it to turn out like either of these two options:

[image]

Or this:

[image]

How can I make it so the items on the bottom row (which don't have enough to fill the space) are the same size as the row(s) above, which would have 3 in each preceding row? I don't want this basically:

[image]

And not looking for this ideally either:

[image]

*(Assume my diagrams everything was perfectly aligned, sorry for the quick sketch)*

I have tried stuff like this:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 16px;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
  min-width: 30%; /* hack so it doesn't shrink too much */
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">hello 1</div>
  <div class="box">hello 2</div>
  <div class="box">hello 3</div>
  <div class="box">hello 4</div>
  <div class="box">hello 5</div>
</div>
```

Notice how my example is like the second to last image, which I want to avoid. I want all items to be the same width, yet only allow 3 per row max.

Note, the elements will be of dynamic height, they will all be the same height potentially, but not given an explicit height. I only gave it an explicit height for demonstration purposes. My real app has content in these boxes like on a landing page.

If flexbox can't do this, that would be good to know. Then I would like to know how to do it another (modern) way somehow.

Also, the number of elements is dynamic too, 3 per row (or really, n per row, for different circumstances and a more general answer).

Comment: Use CSS grid? the first option is a Grid use case

Comment: @TemaniAfif Can you show how it would be done? The number of elements is dynamic too.

Comment: You nail down their width with the `width` property.

Comment: Given you have set the gap in px what would happen on a very narrow viewport? Would you want fewer boxes on the top lne?

Comment: Yeah in that case I will either have fewer boxes (min width on each box), or just hardcode a width on the container, and jump to a separate/unrelated mobile layout at a specific breakpoint. Doesn't matter to me yet.

Answer (score 1):

We can use [css grids](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) to help us achieve what you are looking for

Here is a code snippet that describes scenario one that you have posted in the question

we create a template for a grid and give each area of our grid an identifier. We then assign each of our `box` to a location on the grid

```css
.box{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: aquamarine;
}
#grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 200px 200px;
    grid-template-columns: 200px 200px 200px;
    grid-template-areas: "one two three"
                        "four five empty";
}
#one{
    grid-area: one;
}
#two{
    grid-area: two;
}
#three{
    grid-area: three;
}
#four{
    grid-area: four;
}
#five{
    grid-area: five;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>HTML 5 Boilerplate</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="grid">
      <div class="box" id="one">
        Text
      </div>
      <div class="box" id="two">
        Text
      </div>
      <div class="box" id="three">
        Text
      </div>
      <div class="box"id="four">
        Text
      </div>
      <div class="box"id="five">
        Text
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is too hardcoded, how would you do it with a dynamic number of elements, ranging from 1 element to 14 elements, showing max 3 per row?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `width` (i.e. not min or max-width) set with a percentage value, forbid them to shrink (`flex-shrink: 0`)  and use `margin` on the boxes to get the gaps:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 30%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
  margin: 1.66%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">hello 1</div>
  <div class="box">hello 2</div>
  <div class="box">hello 3</div>
  <div class="box">hello 4</div>
  <div class="box">hello 5</div>
</div>
```

Addition after comment:

To avoid the left and right margins, you can add the following CSS rules which use `nth-child` selectors (and then adjust the margin value a bit to still use the whole width of the container):

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 30%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
  margin: 2.5%;
}
.box:nth-child(3n) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.box:nth-child(3n + 1) {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">hello 1</div>
  <div class="box">hello 2</div>
  <div class="box">hello 3</div>
  <div class="box">hello 4</div>
  <div class="box">hello 5</div>
  <div class="box">hello 6</div>
  <div class="box">hello 7</div>
  <div class="box">hello 8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This adds margin to the left and right of the container though, any way to get rid of that?

Comment: I added a second snippet as an answer to your comment

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS grid can give you a bit more control in a 2D layout.

This snippet is simply a grid with 3 columns and the gap of 16px as in the question.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 16px;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">hello 1</div>
  <div class="box">hello 2</div>
  <div class="box">hello 3</div>
  <div class="box">hello 4</div>
  <div class="box">hello 5</div>
</div>
```

You might want to put in a media query for a really narrow viewport if you want to keep 16px gap. In your question you have the narrowest a box can go as 30% so there's a breakpoint at 10% of the container being 32px.

Comment: How can you dynamically center the last row's 2 items using this approach? That would be the ideal.

Comment: Could  you make that requirement plain in your question?